# Class inheritance? Python?

Tags: python

Here is a program that is supposed to ask a series of questions, save the information, and then display the information back to you. Whenever I run the program, it successfully asks for all of the information, but gives an error when it tries to display a certain part of it.

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 , line 27, in <module>
    main()
 , line 24, in main
    print ("Shift: ", worker.get_shift_number())
AttributeError: 'Worker' object has no attribute 'get_shift_number'
```

The code is:

```
# employee.py
class Employee(object):
    def __init__(self, name, id_number):
        self.__id_number = id_number
        self.__name = name
    def set_name(self, name):
        self.__name = name
    def set_id_number(self, id_number):
        self.__id_number = id_number
    def get_name(self):
        return self.__name
    def get_id_number(self):
        return self.__id_number

class Worker(Employee):
    def __init__(self, name, id_number, shift_number, pay_rate):
        #call superclass __init__ method
        Employee.__init__(self, name, id_number)
        #initialize shift_number and pay_rate attributes
        self.__shift_number = shift_number
        self.__pay_rate = pay_rate
        #mutator functions for shift_number and pay_rate
        def set_shift_number(self, shift_number):
            self.__shift_number = shift_number
        def set_pay_rate(self, pay_rate):
            self.__pay_rate = pay_rate
        #accessor functions for shift_number and pay_rate
        def get_shift_number(self):
            return self.__shift_number
        def get_pay_rate(self):
            return self.__pay_rate
```

Then we have this.

```
#workerprogram.py
import employee

def main():
    #variables
    worker_name= " "
    worker_id = " "
    worker_shift = 0
    worker_pay = 0.0

    #get data attributes
    worker_name = input("Enter the worker name: ")
    worker_id = input("Enter the ID number: ")
    worker_shift = float(input("Enter the shift number: "))
    worker_pay = float(input("Enter the hourly pay rate: "))

    #create an instance of Worker
    worker = employee.Worker(worker_name, worker_id, worker_shift, worker_pay)

    #display information
    print ("Production worker information: ")
    print ("Name: ", worker.get_name())
    print ("ID number: ", worker.get_id_number())
    print ("Shift: ", worker.get_shift_number())
    print ("Hourly Pay Rate: $", worker.get_pay_rate())

main()
```

Indention was wrong like noted, and I also saw that I have my shift_number initializing in the wrong spot. ;(

Thank you!

Comment: Your code comments and exception talk about `ProductionWorker` but your actual code use `Worker()`. Where did `ProductionWorker` go to? If you renamed variables, please re-run your code so that *at the very least* your exception matches the code!

Comment: Ach, this is me writing bad comments. Consider them the same, and I will edit the code to reflect likewise.

Comment: Also, don't use getters and setters in Python code. Python is not Java, just use attributes directly.

Comment: Is your indentation for `Worker()` correct? Because if it is, *all* methods are local names in the `__init__` method. Fix the indentation there.

Comment: Why are you calling `Employee.__init__` instead of `super(Worker, self).__init__`?

Comment: @Hamish 1. Because it's a simpler, clearer and less magical way of doing it. 2. Because the `__init__` functions have different parameters, and then you have to call the inheritance hierarchy in a specific order, and then you can't use `super()` anyway.

Comment: @rob: You answer is correct, you should undelete it.

Comment: @user2901098: The indentation of all but the `__init__()` method of class `Worker`'s methods are (still) wrong.

Comment: @martineau If he updates the question with the corrected code, then there is no question left.

Comment: @Lennart: Exactly...which is why, as you said earlier, rob's answer was correct for the question as originally posted.

Answer (score 0):

Since Rob deleted his correct answer: Your problem is that your indentation is wrong.

However, that's not the only problem with the code. The main one is that its' over complicated as you have accessors/mutators for everything, which is not needed, and will just wast time both for you typing them in and the computer using them.

This is how your code should look:

```
# employee.py
class Employee(object):

    def __init__(self, name, id_number):
        self.id_number = id_number
        self.name = name

class Worker(Employee):

    def __init__(self, name, id_number, shift_number, pay_rate):
        #call superclass __init__ method
        Employee.__init__(self, name, id_number)
        #initialize shift_number and pay_rate attributes
        self.shift_number = shift_number
        self.pay_rate = pay_rate

#workerprogram.py
import employee

def main():
    #variables
    worker_name= " "
    worker_id = " "
    worker_shift = 0
    worker_pay = 0.0

    #get data attributes
    worker_name = input("Enter the worker name: ")
    worker_id = input("Enter the ID number: ")
    worker_shift = float(input("Enter the shift number: "))
    worker_pay = float(input("Enter the hourly pay rate: "))

    #create an instance of Worker
    worker = employee.Worker(worker_name, worker_id, worker_shift, worker_pay)

    #display information
    print ("Production worker information: ")
    print ("Name: ", worker.name)
    print ("ID number: ", worker.id_number)
    print ("Shift: ", worker.shift_number)
    print ("Hourly Pay Rate: $", worker.pay_rate)

main()
```

Although admittedly I don't think you actually want neither shift number nor pay rate as floats, but that can wait to another question.

Comment: Other than the `__init__()` methods, what about all the other method definitions you've left out?

Comment: @martineau They did nothing except waste CPU cycles.

Comment: @martineau No, he got this advice for free, because I'm nice. The claim that it's not OOP is absolute nonsense.

Comment: Hardly. Eliminating all the OP's mutator and accessor methods -- even if they weren't all used in the rest of example code -- makes it no longer OOP. (even if there's still some class definitions with and constructors left).

Comment: @martineau You repeating that absurd claim does not make it true. It remains utter nonsense. OOP does not require separate mutator and accessor methods for each attribute. There are many definitions of OOP, none has that requirement. http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DefinitionsForOo

Comment: As your citation states in its second sentence [NobodyAgreesOnWhatOoIs](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?NobodyAgreesOnWhatOoIs). FWIW in my opinion one requirement is that it entails data [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29) which Wikipedia at least seems to equate with object-oriented programming. Seems you disagree, so let's just agree to disagree.

Comment: @martineau: 1. No, there are people that claim that an OO language should *include support for encapsulation*. That's different from your claim, that everything must be encapsulated. 2. Having getter and and setter-methods for every attribute is your personal definition of encapsulation, that I've never seen before. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29 Your claim that removing these methods makes it not OOP it still utter nonsense. I do not agree to disagree, you are completely wrong.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41034/discussion-between-lennart-regebro-and-martineau)